# Effect of setting self.view = nil

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller with default view associated with it.

If I want to discard the view only not viewcontroller, is it ok to set self.view = nil? So that view gets discarded and new view gets allocated with new values.

I want to fill the view with new UI, based on a condition I did that in viewdidLoad. So If I set self.view = nil, and try to access the view from anywhere, it will again create the view. So the new properties will be set.

Is it a right approach to do it. Or I have to write a separate method to refresh view with new properties.

Please provide me the correct approach to do it.

Comment: Is it recommended way to remove view from self and setting it to nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a *correct* approach, but here is some advice.

Don't interrupt the view lifecycle (make sure `-viewWillAppear:`, `-viewDidAppear:`, `-viewWillDisappear:`, `-viewDidDisappear:` all get called).

Consider multiple view controllers contained within a custom container view controller instead of swapping views. It will keep each view controller focused on a specific task.

Consider having an empty `self.view` and use `-addSubview:`/`-removeFromSuperview` to swap the content. That way you will not need to reset `self.view`.

Comment: So what do you think is the good one to follow in my question apart from viewcontroller containment you suggested above

Comment: @user2634244 It's a matter of how much time you have. Multiple view controllers will be a larger refactor, but will create better, more maintainable code. Swapping subviews will be quicker, but create a messier difficult to maintain view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the default view which comes with the uiviewcontroller. If you want to show the custom `uiview` based on conditions then I would suggest, create your custom `uiview` and then initialize it and add it on your default view for respective conditions.